# Netplan.io failed to start LSB: Netplan Calender Service

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I am trying to set up my server with a static IP, but netplan.io is failing.

```
Process: 10747 execstart (code=exited, status=64).
```

`50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
ethernets:
    enp4s0:
       addresses:
         - 192.168.0.2/24
       gateway4: 192.168.0.1
       dhcp4: false
       dhcp6: false
       nameservers:
          search: [(customname).net]
          addresses: [192.168.0.2, 8.8.8.8]
version: 2
```

---

[image: screenshot of netplan status results]

```
netplan.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=64/USAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing but netplan is different than netplan.io  netplan is some calendar and day planner whereas netplan.io is the package that configures your network interfaces.  Your error is the day/calendar planner.

You should be able to ignore (and remove) netplan unless you actually want to use it.

Comment: I actually have netplan.io, not netplan. But I use it for setting my static IP, and I don't know how else to set it on ubuntu server.

Comment: You have both.  However, the screenshot of the service status is the calendar/day planner (it literally says so on the second line).  Is you machine not getting an IP expected?

Comment: It is set with static on through netplan, and on my router, it says it is set to that and working fine.

Comment: Then you're actually not having any problems other than the "netplan" service failing to start which is in no way related to IP addressing.

It's even more confusing because it looks like the "netplan.io" logs are getting rolled into the "netplan" service status.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I must not understand what netplan is primarily for, that's all I use it for, and it is setting the IP.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not being clear: the logs are showing "netplan" is having issues which is distinct from "netplan.io"  You're using "netplan.io" to set the IP address.  The error is completely unrelated to IP addressing and you should probably just remove netplan using `apt remove -y netplan`

Comment: Okay, I will try that, and see if it causes any problems